# Kirchhoff's Junction Rule

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, conservation-laws

I understand that the Junction rule states that the algebraic sum of currents going into a junction equals the current going out of the Junction.  There is just a wrinkle that I don't understand.  If one of the currents going into the Junction encounters a battery immediately before entering the Junction, how does that affect the current?

Comment: It does not affect the current. The current in any closed circuit is same within and outside all the batteries. If there is a battery just before a junction, the current will pass through the battery and then enter the junction.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a junction or a "Node" as some textbooks call it is a  point that has the same voltage. In a circuit, a node is a set of wire that don't have any elements in them. The node terminates when you encounter a resistor, capacitor, voltage source or a current source. In a general sense, any circuit element that might have voltage drop across it is where a node terminates. Any element in a circuit connects between two nodes (sometimes three like a transistor).

To make the previous explanation clear. Have a look at the following picture:

[image]

In this picture, the set of wires included in the ellipse are a single node. There is another node in this circuit (Can you find it??). All the elements in this circuit R1,R2, and V are connected between Node 1 and the other node.

Now since we clarified the definition of node, let us move to your question. In order for Kirchoff's Junction Rule to apply, you have to apply it to a node. If we want to apply it to Node 1, the currents involved are I1, I2 and I3. I4 is in node 2, thus it is not included in Kirchoff's Junction Rule for Node 1.

In other words, if a current goes into a battery before it enters a junction, that current doesn't belong to the junction it is about to enter. It belongs to the junction from which it came.

Speaking of battery, since it has two terminals. The current flowing into one terminal of the battery is ALWAYS equal to the current leaving it. So in the circuit above I4 is equal to I3. That will hold for any circuit. The introduction to my answer was to explain the general concept.

I hope that answered your question